# Create Live Streaming from an XNA application

Tags: xna, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I would like to create an XNA application and have a live stream with the output of that application (I can render everything in a separate RenderTarget and just use that as a source).

I need this because the application will be shown on a big outdoor display and the only way to get live content there is using live streaming.

Is this possible? How much lag should I expect between the real time rendering and what is actually streamed and displayed on the big panel?

Comment: You should consider long video cables. Making a software application for that might be unnecessarily resource consuming. Besides, there are already many options available, for one you can make a Skype call and share your screen view.

Comment: It's not about the long cable, it's about the entire system that's in place to show video content on that big screen. I don't think  I would be able to make changes to it... so long cable is out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to implement this in your application?  There are plenty of tools available that will just do that for you.

See this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15997/how-do-i-live-stream-games) where software like XSplit is suggested.

It would definitely be easier for you not to have to write this!

Comment: I don't really need to implement this in my application, but I do need a reliable and good performance solution. I am not so sure about image quality & framerate when streaming through 3rd party websites. I'll keep looking. It may simply be too complicated to be feasible for this project. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Update: XSplit looks nice. If I could only get in the same local network as that big outdoor display then I could use the xsplit feature of local streaming. I'll look into it.

Comment: With a decent connection I don't have any problem streaming 1080p from websites like twitch.tv